# Question on bold item numbers only in \begin{enumerate}

Tags: enumerate, bold

I want to Write the following enumeration

> **(A1)** Text 1
>
> **(A2)** Text 2
>
> **(A3)** Text 3

such that `(Ai)` is bold but text `i` is in normal font. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(A\arabic*)}]
  \item foo
  \item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```